# How to export multiple models from a For loop in R (list objects not able to assimilate data.frame)

Tags: r, export, export-to-excel

I need to export some models to excel.

I plan to run 360 models using 36 columns of between 1000 to 4000 + rows

The Data is in a single data.frame imported successfully with no missing data
Models executed without a hitch in .5 to 28 seconds

After declaring the list itself, problems start with models as list object cannot be coerced to double now i need to declare every object as dataframe before using a new object as R refuses to separate any new var from list

Here is the code to start:

```
fitmodel.list=list()
# declare list()

# From here I post models
# Error 1-fitmodel Cannnot write data frame to list object 


        for (i in 2:36){  
        j=10*(i-2)+1
        fitmodel  = ugarchfit(spec=model,data=MD3[1:4175,i]) 
        fitmodel.list[j+1] <- fitmodel
         }
        # 10 models.. from each data column

        Excel_result     <- dplyr::bind_cols(fitmodel.list)
        alt_Excel result <- dplyr::bind_rows(fitmodel.list)
        write.csv(Marketmodels_36indices,
                  "Marketmodels_36indices.csv",
                  row.names=TRUE,append=TRUE)
```

Because of the problem with the list object, I am unable to proceed [`fitmodel = ugarchfit..` does not complete in any case, it is executing nicely outside the loop]

I am able to live without comparing results in excel columns if need arise so pdf or text versions work for me. However, I am sure grabbing the session screen would be out of the question given the resulting model is 100 lines with tests of heteroscedasticity and others

In a similar exercise I was able to export 250 such objects from `lm` using the param names  as `lm$alpha` etc. and read each object into a `dataframe` as a row for each lm output exporting it later to excel. Here the model frame seems to be 100 rows before the out put of residuals which I can get directly from the package (`rugarch`)

Answer (score 0):

The `broom` package was created to turn model output into tidyverse friendly tibbles. I am suspicious that you can use `broom` to coerce your output into tibbles that can be exported to Excel much more easily. You don't really have a reproducible example for me to use to illustrate broom with, so maybe you should look at the package itself:

https://github.com/tidymodels/broom

Broom is under active development so I recommend installing the dev version from github.

Comment: except for the comments and the `library("rugarch")` this is a complete code.

Comment: 1) # in a code block do not get treated as headers. They get treated as comments. Try it. 
2) the `library("rugarch")` bit is critical as the crux of your question is manipulating the result of a `rugarch` function into a `data.frame`. By leaving that bit out, you are leaving question answerers to guess at what your object looks like.

Comment: currently using pairwise plots in `rmgarch` and planning on using `dccfit` objects as long `dataframe` in `ggplot2`